# The missing of the "build" option in right-click menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I added a jar file to the lib folder in android project in Eclipse Indigo. I want to add this file to build, but i don't have build option in the file righ-click menu. Any idea why I don't have it? How can I add it to build anyway? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you can't build the whole project:
   The eclipse project you want to build may have not any builder assigned.
   I suggest you to verify the 'builders' tab in your project settings.
   You may have choosen the wrong project type when creating or importing your project.
2. If you want to add the jar to the build:
   Add the jar to Java Build Path in project properties (as a library)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. It's just an Eclipse normal behaviour.
Check if in menu **Project** -> **Build Automatically** is selected.
To activate the **Build** option just deactivate **Build Automatically** option.

Comment: Phew! This drove me insane. I'm curious how this suddenly got turned on. In a decade of using Eclipse I've never used it, AFAICT there's no keyboard shortcut or toolbar button, and I never use the main menu... weird.